# Java time displaying unexpected results?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

The following is code which takes the three numbers (hours, minutes, and seconds) given in myobject.settime, and display them formatted correctly in military time. The problem is, when I am giving three numbers, the output on my console has three entirely different numbers.

```
public class Clock{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Time myobject = new Time();
        System.out.println(myobject.tomilitary());
        myobject.settime(13, 27, 6 );
        System.out.println(myobject.tomilitary());
    }
}

class Time{
    private int hour, minute, second;

    public void settime(int h, int m, int s){
        hour = ((h>=0 && h<24) ? h : 0); //ternary operator, kind of like an if statement
        hour = ((m>=0 && m<60) ? m : 0);
        hour = ((s>=0 && s<60) ? s : 0);
        System.out.println(h +"\t" +m +"\t" +s +" \t The next line should display these three numbers");
    }

    public String tomilitary() {    
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour , minute , second ); //%02d means display two decimal places for each int after the quote.
    }                                                  
}
```

Right now my output is:

```
 00:00:00
 13 27  6    The next line should display these three numbers
 06:00:00
```

But the last line of my output (06:00:00) should be (13:27:06) please explain what is going on.

Comment: This question should probably be deleted since it looks like a copy & paste error (or typo error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your problem is this:

```
hour = ((h>=0 && h<24) ? h : 0); //ternary operator, kind of like an if statement
minute= ((m>=0 && m<60) ? m : 0);
second = ((s>=0 && s<60) ? s : 0);
```

you assign three times `hour`

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense now, and the reason my output was six o'clock was because the last thing hour was equal to was seconds, and seconds was 6.